# Three.js different texture material on each face

Tags: three.js

I have a `BufferGeometry` object and I want to be able to assign a different texture to each face.

In my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/2ay716mz/ (working example)

I have setup a cube (using custom `BufferGeometry` not `BoxGeometry` seeing as I need other objects that are not cubes).

I have passed an array of materials to the mesh, one side is a texture and the other sides are all different colors.

This all works correctly...however if I try to put the texture material on any face group , other than the group[0] and group[1], then it doesn't work and just shows a color instead.

See in this example where I have set the texture to be the **third** material; it no longer works:  https://jsfiddle.net/2ay716mz/1/

How can I solve this?  Or is this a bug and should be reported to three.js github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine on my end. You just have to assign a new material to each texture you want to use:

```js
const texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

const texURL1 = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Gfp-jagged-rock-texture.jpg';
const texURL2 = 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/patterns/circuit_pattern.png';
const texURL3 = 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/decal/decal-normal.jpg';
const texURL4 = 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/LeePerrySmith/Map-COL.jpg';
const texURL5 = 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/LeePerrySmith/Map-SPEC.jpg';
const texURL6 = 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/pisa/px.png';

const mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: texLoader.load(texURL1)});
const mat2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: texLoader.load(texURL2)});
const mat3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: texLoader.load(texURL3)});
const mat4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: texLoader.load(texURL4)});
const mat5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: texLoader.load(texURL5)});
const mat6 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: texLoader.load(texURL6)});

var material = [
    mat1,
    mat2,
    mat3,
    mat4,
    mat5,
    mat6,
];
```

[Click here for live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/wyp3e5jn/6/)

Comment: The issue actually appears that you need to set the individual materials to separate variables first, then put them into the array.  If you take your example and then switch it so that some of the materials are just plain color; it still works.  But then if you put the material objects straight into the array, without declaring them at separate variables first, it no longer works.  Not sure if this is a bug or a javascript quirk.